# How to identify a clickable button and click it - Selenium

Tags: pandas, selenium-webdriver, button, click

In this webpage

https://www.iadb.org/en/transparency/sanctioned-firms-and-individuals

There is a clickable button called "Export to excel" as shown in the image below.

[image]

I need to click on it from Python (so to download the excel).

I have tried this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./driver/chromedriver")
driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.iadb.org/en/transparency/sanctioned-firms-and-individuals'})
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Export to excel"))).click()
```

But I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-glevorato@provenir.com/Shared drives/Provenir AI Team/Data Science/Data Science/09 AML/OFAC - SDN.py:359
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Export to excel"))).click()

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py:95 in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException
```

Can anyone tell me please what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are 2 issues as I see:**

1. Your locator strategy was incorrect, change as below:

```
# WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Export to excel"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Export to excel']"))).click()
```

2. You need to click on `AcceptCookies` button first, as this element overlaps the desired element and you may get `ElementClickInterceptedException`. See below code for reference.

**Check the below working code:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.iadb.org/en/transparency/sanctioned-firms-and-individuals')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# accept cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept all']"))).click()
# click on Export to excel button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Export to excel']"))).click()
```